# How to delete an input with JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

How to search and delete inputs using JOptionPane, and how to make the program go back to the beginning when user clicks yes after 'do you want to try again'?

The first part of the code is where the inputs go. I'm unsure if OP need to put anything in here to help with the deletion because later I will have to make it delete one of the inputs.

Java:

```java
int i = 0;
while (i < numItems && inp != null) {
    inp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name of expense " + i);
    if (inp != null) {
        expenseNameList[i] = inp;
        inp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter price of " + expenseNameList[i]);
        if (inp != null) {
            expensePriceList[i]=Double.parseDouble(inp);
        }
    }
    i = i + 1;
}

if (inp == null) {
    return;
}
```

The second part of the code is where I have to put the option in for the user to search and delete an input from the array.

```java
//searching for an expense
     String target = "";
     msg = "";
     while (msg.length() == 0 && target != null) {
         target=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which expense did you want to search for...");
         if (target != null) {
             i = 0;
             while(i < numItems) {
                 if (expenseNameList[i].contains(target)) {
                     msg = msg + expenseNameList[i] + ": " + expensePriceList[i] + "\n";
                 }
                 i = i + 1;
           }  
        }

if (msg.length() > 0) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Results found ...\n" + msg);;
      {
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to try again?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");           
          //need to make it go back to the start here   
else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye!");
```

Comment: In my opinion there is no need to use of joptionpane you can afford this by jtextfield.

Comment: Place the code used for searching into a **while** loop. `boolean doLoop = true; while (doLoop) { your code here }`. When you want to exit the loop either `doLoop = false;` or `break;`.